# Directional audio for entity

Tags: aframe

In my gaze-based scene, I have several elements that the user is supposed to find. I would like to have a subtle indicator audio cue eminating from the objects but only if the user is looking very near the element. I've tried playing around with refDistance and the rolloffFactor. I either can't hear the audio cue at all, or I can hear it no matter where I look. How can I localize the audio so the user only hears it when they are 5m from the source?

I already have a different audio cue for when the user looks directly at the object... this is to help guide them to the object.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `maxDistance: 5` and `distanceModel: linear`.

- `maxDistance` - from the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/sound.html#properties_volume) - Maximum distance between the audio source and the listener, after which the volume is not reduced any further.
- `distanceModel`. Here we have `exponential`, `inverse`, and `linear`. The [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function), and [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions) functions, won't simply reach **0**, as they have their asymptotes. If you set the model to `linear` it will change the sound between 100 - 0% linearly between the distance.

Check it out [here](https://glitch.com/~aframe-sound-linear).

---

Although if you find the other `distanceModel`s more realistic, then you'll have to stop / play the sound manually once the distance is greater than 5m.

Comment: I had experimented with maxDistance, but I didn't understand that I had to use the linear function for distanceModel because of asymptotes on the other functions. Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me!

Comment: @schatzkin i hope its understandable :D, glad i could help!

Comment: For some reason, I'm not getting this to work consistently, but also when I look at your example at https://glitch.com/~aframe-sound-linear I'm not hearing the sound anymore.

Comment: it's working for me at firefox, when i'm moving towards the blue cube, are you sure your browser isn't preventing the sound from loading ? May happen with IOS where you need a physical interaction for the sound to play.